# multiply uilabel value by uitextfield value

Tags: math, uitextfield, swift2, calculator, formulas

Im working on an app tha basically multiplies the amount of hours worked by the persons wage. The persons wage is a string called from parse linked to the logged in user.

First I was using the following code but it was not working for decimals i.e label $43 and uiTextField 8.5 hours - it worked fine if the hours were whole numbers like 8. Here is the code I used -

```
@IBOutlet weak var workedHours: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pay: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var moneyMade: UITextField!

@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
moneyMade.text = "$" + ((pay.text! as NSString).integerValue *    (workedHours.text! as NSString).integerValue).description
}
```

I did some research and I've converted the values to integers and it works fine if the input is whole numbers but whenever decimals are used the app crashes. Any ideas why? here is the code I'm using now.

```
@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
    let hours: String = workedHours.text!
    let wage: String = pay.text!

    var myInt: Int? = Int(hours)
    let myInt2: Int? = Int(wage)

    myInt = myInt! * myInt2!

    moneyMade.text! = "\(myInt)"

}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Integer variables can only hold whole numbers.  For values with decimals you need to use Float or Double:

```
  let hoursText = "8.5"
  let wageText  = "12.34"

  var money:Double = 0

  if let hours = Double(hoursText),
     let wage  = Double(wageText)
  {
     money = hours * wage
  }

  moneyMade.text = "\(money)"
```